# Cannot resolve symbol flatMap on Monad constrainted type

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I've been playing with scala cats and ended up stuck with implicits and type constraints.

Assume the following definitions:

```scala
trait Client[F[_]] {

  def fetchPossiblePairs(fetcher: Uri => F[List[String]]): F[List[Rate.Pair]]

  def fetchQuotes(currencyPairs: List[Rate.Pair], fetcher: Uri => F[List[QuoteDTO]]): F[List[Rate]]

  def convertRate(uri: Uri): F[List[QuoteDTO]]

  def symbols(uri: Uri): F[List[String]]

}

object Quotes {
  private def getCurrencyPairs[F[_]: Monad](client: Client[F],
                                            existingRates: Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]): F[List[Rate.Pair]] =
    if (existingRates.isEmpty) {
      client.fetchPossiblePairs(client.symbols)
    } else {
      existingRates.keySet.toList.pure[F]
    }

    private def updateCache(existingRates: Map[Rate.Pair, Rate], newRates: List[Rate]): Map[Rate.Pair, Rate] =
      newRates.foldRight(existingRates)((rate: Rate, acc: Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]) => acc.updated(rate.pair, rate))
}
```

The following implementation works, but looks ugly and not really up to the standards:

```scala
object Quotes {
  private def refreshRatesCache[F[_]: Monad](client: Client[F],
                                             existingRates: Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]): F[Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]] = {
    val currencyPairs1 = getCurrencyPairs(client, existingRates)

    Monad[F]
      .flatMap(currencyPairs1)(currencyPairs => client.fetchQuotes(currencyPairs, uri => client.convertRate(uri)))
      .map(quotes => updateCache(existingRates, quotes))
  }
}
```

Making it more conventional, using the `for` comprehension, IDE shows an error `Cannot resolve symbol flatMap`:

```scala
object Quotes {
  private def refreshRatesCache[F[_]: Monad](client: Client[F],
                                             existingRates: Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]): F[Map[Rate.Pair, Rate]] =
    for {
      currencyPairs <- getCurrencyPairs(client, existingRates)
      //            ^
      //            |--- Cannot resolve symbol flatMap
      //
      rates <- client.fetchQuotes(currencyPairs, uri => client.convertRate(uri))
    } yield updateCache(existingRates, rates)
}
```

And SBT shows a slightly different error:

```
value flatMap is not a member of type parameter F[List[Rate.Pair]]
```

My understanding is that the two implementations are the same, just using the different syntactic sugar.

`getCurrencyPairs[F[_]: Monad](...)` returns a wrapped `List`, `F[List[Rate.Pair]]`, and given the type constraint on `F[_]: Monad` I assume Scala should be able to infer `F extends Monad` and find all the `Monad`'s methods (including `flatMap`).

The entire `for` comprehension works within the same context of `F[_]`, hence seems it is not the type mismatch.

I tried to expand the implicits and `for` comprehension, hence arriving at this ugly implementation:

```scala
    Monad[F]
      .flatMap
        (getCurrencyPairs(client, existingRates))
        (currencyPairs => client.fetchQuotes(currencyPairs, uri => client.convertRate(uri)))
      .map(quotes => updateCache(existingRates, quotes))
```

It does not make a lot of sense to have `(implicit m: Monad[F[_]])`, in my opinion (at least I could not come up with the correct usage for it).

I am not really proficient with Scala implicits, but seems like there is something wrong with my code. Where am I wrong?

The versions I'm using are:

- Scala `2.13.5`
- SBT `1.9.0`
- cats-core `2.5.0`
- cats-effects `2.4.1`

Comment: I'd be happy to give it a spin, but there's too much fluff. Try reducing to a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which means getting rid of stuff like `import app.domain.Rate` etc). Sometimes trying to make a minimal example also helped me in finding the solution on my own!

Comment: Syntactic sugar with type classes is based on extension methods - if the aren't imported into your current scope, they cannot be used. Assuming this `Monad[F]` is from Cats, this would be something from `cats.syntax` (`cats.syntax.all.*` or cats.syntax.monad.*, cats.syntax.functor.*, ...).

Comment: My personal advice, if you are new to all this, use concrete `IO` instead of the tagless final style.

Comment: Note that cats-effect 2.x is *extremely* old and unsupported. It's also slower, has worse ergonomics, and the types provide weaker guarantees about resource safety. As soon as possible you should update to CE 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to missing the import that provides the method.

Add `import cats.syntax.all._`

Comment: That actually solves the issue. But I am still a bit confused by the fact the other line in the `for` comprehension was fine by the compiler